# Ajax response undefined or strange

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

i'm trying to send an array to JS, but i can't have the answer i want.

this is my PHP code:

```
$output = array('total'=>(float)$BHoras[1]'gastas'=>(float)$BHoras[2]); 
echo json_encode($output);
```

and this is my JS code:

```
function ProjectSelect()
{
    var proj = document.getElementById('ProjetosSelect').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'CRM files/TSread.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: ({ProjetosSelect: proj}),
        complete:function(data) 
        {
            var Horas = data.responseText;
            alert(Horas); // response -> {"total":146,"gastas":84.5}
            alert(Horas[3]); // response -> o
        }

    });
}
```

i only want the "146" and "84.5".

i tried to do, `alert(Horas['total'])`, `alert(Horas.total)`, but give me `undefined`

Comment: First of all, you have a mistake in php code, it should be `$output = array('total'=>(float)$BHoras[1], 'gastas'=>(float)$BHoras[2]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just specify `dataType: "json"` and jQuery will parse response for you:

```
function ProjectSelect()
{
    var proj = $('#ProjetosSelect').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'CRM files/TSread.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: ({ProjetosSelect: proj}),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(Horas) 
        {
            alert(Horas.total);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: i change a bit nad now works, thks =D
function ProjectSelect()
{
 var proj = document.getElementById('ProjetosSelect').value;
 $.ajax({
  url: 'CRM files/TSread.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: ({ProjetosSelect: proj}),
  dataType: "json",
  complete:function(data) 
  {
   console.log(data.responseJSON.total);
  }
  
 });
}

Answer (score 1):

On server side you could try TracKer note. And you can add a header too.

```
<?php
$output = array('total'=>(float)$BHoras[1], 'gastas'=>(float)$BHoras[2]);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use `camelCase`, instead of  `PascalCase` naming convention for you PHP variables.